# What is the geometric significance of the definition of the derivative for complex-valued functions?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, derivatives, analytic-functions

Roughly speaking, a function $f:\mathbf R^2\to\mathbf R^2$ is differentiable at $\mathbf v$ if there is a linear transformation $Df(\mathbf v)$ such that $f(\mathbf v+\mathbf h)\approx f(\mathbf v)+Df(\mathbf v)\mathbf h$. If, in addition, $f$ is differentiable as a map from $\mathbf C$ to $\mathbf C$, then we require that this linear transformation is complex multiplication, which rotates and scales the vector $\mathbf h$. This means that if you consider a tiny disk $D$ centred at $\mathbf v$, then (in the limit) the image of $D$ under $f$ will also be a disk.

My question is: from a geometric perspective, why does the fact that holomorphic functions map disks to disks give them such nice properties—e.g. a function which is differentiable once is infinitely differentiable.

Comment: You can notice from the Cauchy Riemann equations that holomorphic functions are geometrically nice in the following informal way: they do not tear the complex plane. The derivative with respect to the real part is perpendicular to the derivative with respect to the imaginary part; the derivative of the real part of $f$ is perpendicular to the derivative of the imaginary part; the perpendicular axes of $\Re,\Im$ are preserved, “not torn”. This is the way I intuitively explained the Cauchy Riemann equations before I understood their formal derivation.

Comment: I expect there’s a nice explanation in Tristan Needham’s beautiful book “Visual Complex Analysis”, though I haven’t checked.

Comment: This isn't a geometric explanation, but the usual answer is "because Green's theorem." (The Cauchy-Riemann equations imply Cauchy's theorem, which leads to the Cauchy integral formula.)

Comment: This is a fundamental question. It is answered everywhere. Look for example at [holomorphic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function). It is about the right level of detail. And starts with the correct addition. Only an open set $U$ is needed for a holomorphic attribute, not a disc. And if a disc then an open discs without boundary. It shows examples and theories about the differences between both definitions of $f$'s. It names the concept holomorphic up to on single points sets. What are the examples for deforming a disc. This offers paths to go further in the topic and re